# MenuItem IsCheckable property. The UI does not indicate that the menu item is checkable

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I *think* that when I used the IsCheckable property before, the UI showed the check box.

Now however there is no indication that the menu item is checkable.
Is this the correct behaviour?

(When I click the menu item, the check mark toggles.)

[image]
[image]

```
<MenuItem Header="Tools" Name="miTools">
    <MenuItem Header="Log data communication">
        <MenuItem Header="Log complete data packets" Name="miLogFullPacket" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="False" />
        <MenuItem Header="Log fragments of data packet" Name="miLogPacketFragment" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="False" Click="logDataPacketFragments_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Show log file"  />
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Settings..." Click="settingsChange_Click"/>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: I cannot speak for WPF, but that is the standard behaviour for non-WPF menu bar items. Just look at Windows's own Notepad for a minimalistic example.

Comment: @hvd I take your point. But for some reason I have it in my mind that I saw the checkbox indicated in the menu item in some previous programming... But my brain is old and tired, I am probably wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the *Style* of the default menu has the following code:

```
<!-- CheckMark in resources -->
<PathGeometry x:Key="Checkmark" Figures="M0,2 L0,4.8 L2.5,7.4 L7.1,2.8 L7.1,0 L2.5,4.6 z" />

<!-- Template for SubmenuItem --> 
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="17" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="14"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- Place for Icon --> 
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

            <!-- CheckMark path: initially hidden -->
            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="4,0,6,0" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>

            <!-- MenuItem Text -->
            <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText" Grid.Column="2" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,2,0,2" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

    <!-- ... -->

        <!-- This show CheckMark -->
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>

    <!-- ... -->
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In trigger this condition is checked (IsChecked == True) only, but there is no action, if (IsCheckable == True). *MSDN* sample of MenuItem [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has the following code:

```
<!-- ... -->

<Border Name="Check" Width="13" Height="13" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="6,0,6,0" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}">
    <Path Name="CheckMark" Width="7" Height="7" Visibility="Hidden" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Stroke="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0" />
</Border>

<ContentPresenter Name="HeaderHost" Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>

<!-- MenuItem Text -->
<TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText" Grid.Column="2" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" Margin="5,2,0,2" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />

<!-- ... -->

<ControlTemplate.Triggers>               

    <!-- ... -->

    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="IsCheckable" Value="true">
        <Setter TargetName="Check" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    </Trigger>

    <!-- ... -->

</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

If the MenuItem (IsCheckable == true) it shows the Border "Check" with empty content (without CheckMark).

**OUTPUT:** Use the *MSDN* style and change it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I am not that experienced with xaml, I find it kind of spaghetti like, but maybe not as bad as perl :)